# BigQuery to Kafka Topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I have a data that is loaded in to BigQuery and I would need to connect BigQuery to Kafka as a source for publishing data to Kafka topic once a day. Since there isn't a BigQuery source connector, so what would be the best way to publish BigQuery data to Kafka topic.

Comment: How did the data get into BigQuery? The common pattern here is to stream from the source into Kafka, and then into BigQuery as needed. This is probably why there isn't a BQ source connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various options. I would use batch [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) pipeline running on [Google Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) for this task. It has Java and Python SDK.

For example in Java you can read data with [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html) and then write it with [KafkaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html).

Something like this:

```
//read rows from BQ
PCollection<TableRow> weatherData = pipeline.apply(
    BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from("clouddataflow-readonly:samples.weather_stations"));

// some data processing steps


// write pairs to Kafka topic
PCollection<KV<Long, String>> kvColl = ...;
kvColl.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>write()
    .withBootstrapServers("broker_1:9092,broker_2:9092")
    .withTopic("results")

    .withKeySerializer(LongSerializer.class)
    .withValueSerializer(StringSerializer.class)
);
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!